# r multiple for loop aggregate result in matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to do a `for loop` of 50 times and each time generating three columns and 13 rows of data which I store in a matrix, so the final product should have 13 rows but 150 columns. That is, each time, the `for loop` result is aggregated to the right of the previous one.
Here is my attempt:

```
predict.data<-matrix(nrow=13,ncol = 150)
for (i in 1:50){
  x <- rnorm(15)
  y <- x + rnorm(15)
  new <- data.frame(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.5))

  for (j in 1:nrow(new)){ 
    predict.data[j,] <- predict(lm(y ~ x), new, interval = "prediction")
    colnames(predict.data) <- paste(c("fit", "lwr","upr"), 1:50)
  }
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

maybe I am missing a point somewhere in the code.
I also need to paste the column names consecutively: fit1, lwr1, upr1, fit2, lwr2, upr2, ...

Could somebody help me to correct and adjust this fo

### expected result will look like something like:

```
fit1    lwr1    upr1    fit2    lwr2    upr2    …   fit50   lwr50   upr50
1,81    1,76    1,44    1,22    1,70    1,14    …   1,97    1,45    1,16
1,67    1,46    1,52    1,89    1,43    1,02    …   1,86    1,38    1,69
1,73    1,76    1,53    1,35    1,44    1,74    …   1,92    1,22    1,01
1,72    1,89    1,12    1,55    1,81    1,21    …   1,47    1,79    1,99
1,30    1,30    1,04    1,07    1,07    1,95    …   1,20    1,08    1,59
1,64    1,94    1,73    1,10    1,59    1,28    …   1,89    1,62    1,14
2,00    1,56    1,24    1,10    1,50    1,16    …   1,59    1,25    1,88
1,64    1,03    1,58    1,84    1,57    1,33    …   1,96    1,75    1,01
1,50    1,51    1,64    1,32    1,46    1,10    …   1,71    1,68    1,35
1,94    1,50    1,28    1,64    1,90    1,54    …   1,25    1,51    1,96
1,24    1,67    1,74    1,21    1,29    1,81    …   1,63    1,91    1,82
1,81    1,90    1,28    1,85    1,59    1,13    …   1,55    1,25    1,98
1,35    1,12    1,26    1,52    1,25    1,46    …   1,75    1,84    1,09
```

### new update

I have another problem regarding the case when the `new` is a matrix and instead of `lm` i have `cv.glmnet` from package "glmnet". I only get in the final result one third of the data, that is only 50 columns instead of 150. and the colnames are not right anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work...

```
library(magrittr) # sorry I like pipes

predict.data <- list() # versitle across data structures

for (i in 1:50){

    x <- rnorm(15)
    y <- x + rnorm(15)
    new <- data.frame(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.5))

    predict.data[[i]] <- predict(lm(y ~ x), new, interval = "prediction") %>%
                     magrittr::set_colnames(., paste0(colnames(.), i))

}

predict.data %<>% do.call(cbind, .) # make your wide matrix
```

Comment: thanks, why does it stop at the `fit34`, I can't see the rest of the columns?

Comment: do you get this message `[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted xx rows ]`?

Comment: you can change the cut off for max items with `options(max.print = 1000)`

Comment: I have another problem regarding the case when the `new` is a matrix and instead of `lm` i have `cv.glmnet` from package "glmnet". I only get in the final result one third of the data, that is only 50 columns instead of 150. and the colnames are not right anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With base R. I use `cbind`

```
predict.data<-NULL  #empty object
for (i in 1:50){
  x <- rnorm(15)
  y <- x + rnorm(15)
  new1 <- data.frame(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.5))

  for (j in 1:nrow(new1)){
    res <- predict(lm(y ~ x), new1, interval = "prediction")
    colnames(res) <- paste0(c("fit", "lwr","upr"), i)
    predict.data<-cbind(predict.data,res)
  }
}
```